# Remove public access address of AWS EC2s and just use AWS ELB instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

With this setup I can load balance traffic to two EC2 instances successfully using ELB's DNS address. However, I can also **directly access** both EC2 instances using their addresses too which feels like a security issue to me! What do I need to change in order to prevent direct access to EC2 instances from Internet and just carry on using ELB for access please?

Note: If I set `associate_public_ip_address` as `false`, I cannot access anything at all because target groups (EC2s) become "Unhealthy".

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.4.4"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.30.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "development"
  region  = local.region
}

# -- VARS ----------------------------------------------------------------------

locals {
  project = "api"

  region = "eu-west-1"

  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  subnets = {
    "a1" = {
      az   = "${local.region}a"
      cidr = "10.0.1.0/24"
    },
    "b1" = {
      az   = "${local.region}b"
      cidr = "10.0.2.0/24"
    }
  }

  ec2_ami           = "ami-0fb2f0b847d44d4f0" // Amazon Linux 2023 AMI 2023.1.20230705.0 x86_64 HVM kernel-6.1
  ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

# -- VPC -----------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = local.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.project}-vpc"
  }
}

# -- ROUTE TABLE ---------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_route_table" "route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.project}-route-table"
  }
}

# -- INTERNET GATEWAY ----------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.project}-internet-gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "internet_gateway" {
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.route_table.id
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.internet_gateway.id
}

# -- SUBNET --------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = local.subnets

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  availability_zone = each.value.az

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.project}-subnet-${each.key}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet" {
  for_each = local.subnets

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet[each.key].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route_table.id
}

# -- EC2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_security_group" "http" {
  name        = "${local.project}-http"
  description = "Allow inbound and outbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 22"
    from_port   = "22"
    to_port     = "22"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 80"
    from_port   = "80"
    to_port     = "80"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 443"
    from_port   = "443"
    to_port     = "443"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    description = "Allow outbound traffic"
    from_port   = "0"
    to_port     = "0"
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  for_each = local.subnets

  ami                         = local.ec2_ami
  instance_type               = local.ec2_instance_type
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.subnet[each.key].id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.http.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true   # <- I think this is a security risk

  user_data = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
echo "<html><body>Hello from subnet ${each.key}</body></html>" > /var/www/html/index.html
  EOF

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.project}-ec2-subnet-${each.key}"
  }
}

# -- LOAD BALANCER -------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_lb" "application" {
  name = "${local.project}-application-load-balancer"

  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.http.id]
  subnets            = [for sub in aws_subnet.subnet : sub.id]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "application" {
  name = "${local.project}-http-application"

  port                          = 80
  protocol                      = "HTTP"
  vpc_id                        = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  load_balancing_algorithm_type = "least_outstanding_requests"

  health_check {
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    port                = 80
    path                = "/"
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 3
    timeout             = 10
    interval            = 30
    matcher             = 200
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ec2" {
  for_each = aws_instance.ec2

  port             = 80
  target_id        = each.value.id
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.application.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "application" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.application.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.application.arn
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.project}-application-load-listener"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this while sharing a single security group across all your resources. You need to have two separate security groups, one for your load balancer, and one for your EC2 instances. In the EC2 security group you would configure it to only allow inbound HTTP requests from the load balancer's security group.

Here's an example of how those security groups would look:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2" {
  name        = "${local.project}-ec2"
  description = "Allow inbound and outbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 22"
    from_port   = "22"
    to_port     = "22"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 80"
    from_port   = "80"
    to_port     = "80"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb.id]
  }

  egress {
    description = "Allow outbound traffic"
    from_port   = "0"
    to_port     = "0"
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "lb" {
  name        = "${local.project}-lb"
  description = "Allow inbound and outbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 80"
    from_port   = "80"
    to_port     = "80"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow inbound traffic from port 443"
    from_port   = "443"
    to_port     = "443"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    description = "Allow outbound traffic"
    from_port   = "0"
    to_port     = "0"
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After reflecting the changes, EC2's are accessible only via ELB from Internet and no more direct EC2 access anymore which is great. I still had to keep `associate_public_ip_address = true` to make things work though but I understand why because: 1) instances go "unhealthy". 2) The field name makes me think "if you want to expose EC2 to Internet, set it as true". Am I still doing something wrong or is it an expected behaviour/setting?

Comment: I meant to say "I DON'T understand" in comment above (cannot edit it).

Comment: Your EC2 instances need to download things from the Internet on startup. Those `yum` commands require Internet access to work. Your EC2 instances need a public IP to connect to the Internet in order to complete their setup process. You would have to create a NAT Gateway in your VPC, and move the EC2 instances into separate subnets that have a route to the NAT Gateway, if you wanted to remove their public IP addresses.

Comment: Got it. Given they are not directly accessible from Internet anymore, that's fine to keep the setting. Thank you for the help again. Much appreciated.